SIP error after power loss
I was in the process of updating SIP when I lost power. Now running SIP gives this error:
pi@raspberrypisip:~/SIP $ sudo python3 sip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sip.py", line 21, in <module>
    import gv
  File "/home/pi/SIPnew/gv.py", line 22
    ver_str = f"{major_ver}.{minor_ver}.{revision - old_count}"
                                                              ^

I have tried python and python 3, getting the same error.
Help.

is that the whole error message?

Have you tried uninstalling then re-installing it?  It's impossible for software to meaningfully handle a power loss and so pip/apt may not necessarily be able to pick up where it left off.

yes that is the entire message.  i have tried reinstalling Sip and python

restore from backup, and try again
